# Why is this binary search giving me an infinite loop?

Tags: c, arrays, infinite-loop, binary-search

I am trying to do a binary search. I really can't think of why I am getting an infinite loop? Is is because I ignored the null value somewhere? The value, values[], and n are being provided by a different file, and they are written by someone else, and are, for the purposes of this question, perfectly coded.

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    int upper_bound = n - 1;
    int lower_bound = 0;
    int middle = (upper_bound + lower_bound) / 2; 

    while (lower_bound <= upper_bound)
    {
        if (values[middle] == value)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (values[middle] > value)
        {
            upper_bound = middle - 1; 
        }
        else if (values[middle] < value)
        {
            lower_bound = middle + 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Thank you all so much.

Comment: It's not really a binary search, then, is it.  A binary search requires an ordered (sorted) collection.  Is yours ordered?  If your collection is not ordered, then you'll need to sort it first.  A binary search should also close the distance between the closest lower bound and the closest upper bound by half with each iteration.

Comment: the last else will never be called and `values[value] == value` does not change

Comment: I do have a separate function to sort the array from least to greatest , but that function comes after this function. Does the order of functions matter?

Comment: Absolutely it matters.  You cannot do a binary search on unordered data.  Moreover, even if your collection is ordered, your search algorithm, as shown, is not a binary search.  If it is intended to be a binary search, then it is flawed.

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn, I added that last else because I thought I needed to end an if, else if,... argument with an else. But I've also tried it without the last else. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the value of `middle` inside the `while` loop:

```
while (lower_bound <= upper_bound){
int middle = (upper_bound + lower_bound) / 2;
...
}
```

As the value of `middle` should change every time you are changing the value of either `lower_bound` or `upper_bound`.

Comment: int middle = (upper_bound + lower_bound) / 2 + lower_bound;

Comment: @JoelGreen: I think you really meant to say `middle = (upper_bound - lower_bound) / 2 + lower_bound)`

Answer (score 0):

the middle value is fixed. It is not changing as the values of `upper_bound` and `lower_bound` are changing.